# If and else error BATCH

Tags: batch-file, cmd

if and else in batch i have tried many time to get this working but i cant seem to find the problem can anyone help?

```
FOR /R "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO
if exist "%%~a\yes.txt" (
    echo yes
) else 
(
    md Pictures
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read the manual!
`if /?`

There is described that the parenthesis must be on the same line where the `ELSE` is.

```
FOR /R "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO (
  if exist "%%~a\yes.txt" (
    echo yes
  ) else (
    md Pictures
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the syntax of the cmd shell, commands are terminated by the end-of-line, unless there is still a "()" open.  Thus, in your code above, the line

```
FOR /R  "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO
```

is the complete `for` loop - you are looping and `DO`ing nothing.  To continue the `FOR` command onto another line, you need to add a "(":

```
FOR /R  "C:\Program Files"  %%a IN (.) DO (
```

Now you can continue the command with your `If` statement.  The same holds for your `If` statement.  You typed

```
if exist "%%~a\yes.txt" (
    echo yes
) else
```

and so the "(" at the end of the line with the `IF` continues it to the matching ")" on the line with the `else`, but without a "(" after the `else` on the same line, your `if` command is terminated, and syntactically incorrect.

But I'm not sure that your code is really doing what you want.  It will attempt to create the directory "Pictures" *in what ever directory you execute the command*, and it will attempt to create it repeatedly, each time it finds some sub-directory of "C:\Program files" that does not contain a file "yes.txt" (which will be lots of directories).  So you will create "tmp" the first time through, and then all subsequent attempts will just result in an error message.

The key thing here is that the loop will assign the directory names to %%a, *but it does not do a "CD" to that directory*, so you are still "in" the directory where you start the loop.

What are you actually trying to do?